# how to get a object to initialize object with variables set in gms

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-studio-1.4

I have a function to create a textbox object and set it values but the create event runs before that.
this is the function code:

```
text_obj = instance_create(0, 0, obj_character_text);
text_obj.text = text;
text_obj.face = face;
text_obj.name = name;
```

and this is the create event:

```
current_text_index = 0;
current_text = string_char_at(text, current_text_index);
alarm[0] = 5;
```

How can I get the create event to run after the variables have been set?

Comment: One workaround I've found is to place the code, that's required in the create event to go last, in the function code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`instance_create` runs the Create event before returning, so variables assigned afterwards would not be set as of the Create event running.

I have an [old blog post](https://yal.cc/gamemaker-create-event-arguments/) about the matter; the easiest is to store your desired init in a global variable, suppose

```
global.character_text_init = { text: text, face: face, name: name };
```

and in Create

```
var init = global.character_text_init;
global.character_text_init = undefined; // so that we get a clean error if we forget
text = init.text;
face = init.face;
name = init.name;
// ...
```